# Jquery: How to have multiple variable value combinations change another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap form where input values change the value of my variables. These variables then, within a certain combination, will then change the value of a different variable.

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;
var d = 0;

if ((a >= 1) && (b >= 1) && (c >= 1)) {
    var d = 3;
} else if ((a >= 1) && (b >= 0) && (c >= 0)) {
    var d = 3;
} else if ((a >= 1) && (b >= 0) && (c >= 1)) {
    var d = 3;
} else if ((a >= 0) && (b >= 1) && (c >= 1)) {
    var d = 3;
} else {
    var d = 0;
}
```

As of right now, when the form is changed on keyup the first IF statement combination will work, however the other ELSE IF statements will not.

I need the ability to have any one of the IF or ELSE IF combinations to then change the value of variable D.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you using the Chrome console to debug this, step through the code, inspect the variable values, etc?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Chrome console and event have readonly input fields that display the variable values right away.

Comment: The problem is, not all variable combinations (A & B & C) are not correctly changing variable D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you said, but if I understand you must change else if for simple if.

Take a look to this solution:

```
var a = 0; var b = 0; var c = 0;
var d = 0;
if ((a >= 1) && (b >= 1) && (c >= 1)) {
    var d = 3;
}
if ((a >= 1) && (b >= 0) && (c >= 0)) {
    var d = 3;
}
if ((a >= 1) && (b >= 0) && (c >= 1)) {
    var d = 3;
}
if ((a >= 0) && (b >= 1) && (c >= 1)) {
    var d = 3;
} else { var d = 0; }
```